# How can I calculate overlap of different strings in sql?

Tags: sql, teradata

How can I calculate overlap of different strings in `sql`?(I am in teradata environment)
For example:
`compare(gatech,gt)=gt or 2`

Comment: Overlap based on which rules? Character exists in both? What if characters are repeated? Same order of chars? Etc.

Comment: Hi Dnoeth, Thanks, I want chracter existes in both, repeated characters are counted,order is meaningless, (gttaech, ttgf) = 3 is good enough.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a task for [NGRAM](https://docs.teradata.com/reader/WX0vkeB8F3JQXZ0HTR~d0Q/5A5bir1frdbV_VICC7jYiw):

```
NGRAM('gttaech', 'ttgf')
```